# Start docker from this bash script and keep it running?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell

I am trying to understand how to prevent the bash script below from exiting after it starts running the docker along with executing some initial commands. I want to be able to interact at the terminal thereafter. Instead, it simply exits. **I think the part I am trying to figure out is at the end of the script but I added the entire script for clarity**.

My knowledge on shell scripting and docker is limited. What I understand is there are two functions here which help map the appropriate folders from my own machine directory to a docker directory and also append some ENV variables which I need in order to import some folders and python modules.

What I have tried so far:

1. Added -d -it when I run the script at the terminal.
2. Added -d -it as OPTIONS to the docker run command at the end of this file.
3. removed exit at the end of the script

I would appreciate some explanation on why method 2 did not work.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#################################################
# Shell script that simulates JModelica using
# a docker image of JModelica.
#
# The main purpose of this script is to export
# MODELICAPATH and PYTHONPATH with their values
# updated for the docker, and to mount the
# required directories.
#################################################
set -e
IMG_NAME=ubuntu-1804_jmodelica_trunk
DOCKER_USERNAME=michaelwetter

# Function declarations
function create_mount_command()
{
   local pat="$1"
   # Each entry in pat will be a mounted read-only volume
   local mnt_cmd=""
   for ele in ${pat//:/ }; do
      mnt_cmd="${mnt_cmd} -v ${ele}:/mnt${ele}:ro"
   done

   # On Darwin, the exported temporary folder needs to be /private/var/folders, not /var/folders
   # see https://askubuntu.com/questions/600018/how-to-display-the-paths-in-path-separately
   if [ `uname` == "Darwin" ]; then
       mnt_cmd=`echo ${mnt_cmd} | sed -e 's| /var/folders/| /private/var/folders/|g'`
   fi
   echo "${mnt_cmd}"
}

function update_path_variable()
{
  # Prepend /mnt/ in front of each entry of a PATH variable in which the arguments are
  # separated by a colon ":"
  # This allows for example to create the new MODELICAPATH
  local pat="$1"
  local new_pat=`(set -f; IFS=:; printf "/mnt%s:" ${pat})`
  # Cut the trailing ':'
  new_pat=${new_pat%?}
  echo "${new_pat}"
}

# Export the MODELICAPATH
if [ -z ${MODELICAPATH+x} ]; then
    MODELICAPATH=`pwd`
else
    # Add the current directory to the front of the Modelica path.
    # This will export the directory to the docker, and also set
    # it in the MODELICAPATH so that JModelica finds it.
    MODELICAPATH=`pwd`:${MODELICAPATH}
fi

# Create the command to mount all directories in read-only mode
# a) for MODELICAPATH
MOD_MOUNT=`create_mount_command ${MODELICAPATH}`
# b) for PYTHONPATH
PYT_MOUNT=`create_mount_command ${PYTHONPATH}`

# Prepend /mnt/ in front of each entry, which will then be used as the MODELICAPATH
DOCKER_MODELICAPATH=`update_path_variable ${MODELICAPATH}`
DOCKER_PYTHONPATH=`update_path_variable ${PYTHONPATH}`

# If the current directory is part of the argument list,
# replace it with . as the docker may have a different file structure
cur_dir=`pwd`
bas_nam=`basename ${cur_dir}`
arg_lis=`echo $@ | sed -e "s|${cur_dir}|.|g"`

# Set variable for shared directory
sha_dir=`dirname ${cur_dir}`

# Check if the python script should be run interactively (if -i is specified)
while [ $# -ne 0 ]
do
    arg="$1"
    case "$arg" in
        -i)
            interactive=true
            DOCKER_INTERACTIVE=-t
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

# --user=${UID} \

docker run \
  --user=${UID} \
  -i \
  $DOCKER_INTERACTIVE \
  --detach=false \
  ${MOD_MOUNT} \
  ${PYT_MOUNT} \
  -v ${sha_dir}:/mnt/shared \
  -e DISPLAY=${DISPLAY} \
  -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
  --rm \
  ${DOCKER_USERNAME}/${IMG_NAME} /bin/bash -c \
  "export MODELICAPATH=${DOCKER_MODELICAPATH}:/usr/local/JModelica/ThirdParty/MSL && \
   export PYTHONPATH=${DOCKER_PYTHONPATH} && \
  cd /mnt/shared/${bas_nam}"
exit $?
```

Comment: Generally you should think of a container like wrapping around a program.  Given this script, how and why would you want an interactive shell "in the script"?  Usually you'd want to set up the container to actually run the program packaged in the container, rather than an interactive shell.  Also look at the `docker run -e` and `-w` options to set environment variables and the working directory for a container.

Comment: If you have a script this long to map host paths into a container, remap the host's `$TMPDIR`, and push code into the container via bind mounts, you should also consider whether just running the process directly on the host will be simpler to set up than working around all of Docker's isolation features.

Comment: Precisely, the docker image has some features which make it worth using the container than running on the host.